# ActionLink parameter shows me length

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Action Link on my view and then it clicked it needs to go update view with Id.But it shows me the Length.

View

```
@Html.ActionLink("Update", "UpdateEmployee","Employee", new { id = item.EmpId })
```

When i click it it shows me the URL ,
`http://localhost:7631/Employee/UpdateEmployee?Length=8`

Because Length 8 is wrong and corret way is
`http://localhost:7631/Employee/UpdateEmployee/1`

Comment: Show your `UpdateEmployee` action and the related `Route` definition.

Answer (score 2):

I Found the Answer,

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Update", "UpdateEmployee","Employee", new { id = item.EmpId },null)
```

Comment: If your view is in the same controller you can omit the controller name and use a shorter overload, @Html.ActionLink("Update", "UpdateEmployee", new { id = item.EmpId })